# How to play in Python the sequence of audio files one after another?

Tags: python, audio

I would like to make in Python 3.7.3 an audio player, which will play songs in a sequence, one after another.
Here you will see the function "JustPlay". Instead of playing one after another it plays only the first song. Before it was without "break" and it played only the last one. How to make it playing in a sequence one after another?

```
from tkinter import *
from pygame import mixer
import random

root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

subMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="Open")
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit")

subMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help",menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="About us")

mixer.init()
root.title("Melody")
text = Label(root, text = "The name of an album")
text.pack()

a = "C:/Pathway1"
b = "C:/Pathway2"
c = "C:/Pathway3"
d = [a, b, c]

def song1():
  mixer.music.load(a)
  mixer.music.play()

def song2():
  mixer.music.load(b)
  mixer.music.play()

def song3():
  mixer.music.load(c)
  mixer.music.play()

def stop_music():
  mixer.music.stop()

def set_vol(val):
  volume = int(val) / 100
  mixer.music.set_volume(volume)

def Randomplay():
  mixer.music.load(random.choice(d))
  mixer.music.play()

def JustPlay(): 
  for x in d:
   mixer.music.load(x)
   mixer.music.play()
   break


playbtn1 = Button(root, text="song1", command=song1)
playbtn1.pack()

playbtn2 = Button(root, text="song2", command=song2)
playbtn2.pack()

playbtn3 = Button(root, text="song3", command=song3)
playbtn3.pack()

randombtn = Button(root, text="Random", command=Randomplay)
randombtn.pack()

justplaybtn = Button(root, text="Play", command=JustPlay)
justplaybtn.pack()

stopbtn = Button(root, text="Stop", command=stop_music)
stopbtn.pack()

scale = Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=set_vol)
scale.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .queue() function in mixer.music to queue up a bunch of songs - so I would load a, queue the rest and then run play()

```py
mixer.music.load(a)
[mixer.music.queue(track) for track in [b,c,d]]
mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work on my computer. I tried to do it other way with queue but it still plays only the song I load (a in this case).

Answer (score 0):

there u can use threading module.Which allows u to play music sequentially and use ur TK.
Just write the function like :

```
def the_nexts(index,size,musiclist):
while index<size-1:
    current=musiclist[index]
    mixer.music.queue(current)
    song_mut = MP3(current)
    song_length = song_mut.info.length
    converted_song_length = time.strftime('%S', time.gmtime(song_length))
    time.sleep(float(converted_song_length))
```

Where **musiclist** is the list that contains the name of musics in string. You can initialize the index by 0. Size-length of list
song_mut = MP3(current)-->do **from mutagen.mp3 import MP3** it's permitting you to know the length of music in seconds,so you will add to the queue the songs after the end of the previous song (It's needed because `while` will iterate with index+1 after the end of music only.)
The main call is `Thread(target=the_nexts,args=(index,size,musiclist)).start()`